Multi-attribute similarity search across millions or records based on criteria
Problem description: I am trying to perform an efficient multi-attribute similarity search across millions of records in a database. However, my process requires an hierarchical order of criteria for each matching case.
For example, consider that my records look like this:
Item(name, number, user)
And I have a variety of matching criteria with hierarchical order:

Criterion A: Match with records with the same name and number
Criterion B: Match with records with similar name and user

I need to find an efficient way to match a user request with my data.
So far I have build a process using Python (because I am most familiar with), where I first load my entire database (only the tables I need though which are still a couple million rows) in a in-memory SQLite DB. I chose to do that so I do not increase traffic in my main DB during this process.
Then, per user request, I iterate through each criterion in order to find a proper match. The main problem is that for each criterion I have to perform a READ operation on the in-memory DB in order to get the matches that account for the specific criterion (I try to utilize SQL as much as possible) and then perform any post-processing using Python if needed. Also, if a record is matched with any Criterion, we continue to the next one (Since criteria are in hierarchical order!)
Note, that I run each user request in parallel to be more efficient.
Thus, far I have managed to process 100 requests in ~1 Hour using this method but this is not as efficient as I would like it to be.
I also researched vector DBs and other tools (Pandas, Polars, DuckDB) but I am not sure whether they can be used for my use-case.
Any tips on how to improve my process are welcome!

Sounds like you should be using an SQL approach initially.

@D.L I did initially use SQL but it turned out to be hard to maintain & scale and resulted in heavy traffic on my main database. Is there something else I could try SQL-wise maybe that I haven't thought of?

it depends on the size of the dataset that one expects to retrieve from the query. if the resulting dataset is large, then this will be problematic and better done locally.  if the returned data is small, then perform the query on the original data in the database.

What is the main database server? What indexing is implemented?

I constructed my process so each Criterion "Group" first queries the records that mostly describe it. I.e., for "B" I query all records with the same name, each result may return 10-20K records, which I then process using Python, if needed. However, now that you mention it I should probably check the configuration of the Indexing in the database. Thanks for the advice!
